# List of acceptable initial characters for a bash variable

Tags: bash, variable, syntax

What are the acceptable characters in a bash variable?

Can someone point me to the place in the bash man page that describes the acceptable name for a bash variable?

I looked and came up with a lot of info (see question edits), but not a clear answer.

Comment: May be [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821201/1944384).

Comment: So...  what is the _question_?

Comment: @DopeGhoti edited for clarity

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it's a great write-up for the rules for variable names, there does not appear to be an actual _question_ in this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can assign values to variables (with `var=value`). There's a [fine distinction between a *parameter* and a *variable*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters):

> A *parameter* is an entity that stores values. It can be a *name*, a number, or one of the special characters listed below. A *variable* is a parameter denoted by a *name*.

[and a name is defined as](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#index-name):

> *name*
>   A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. *Name*s are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an *identifier*.

(That's the definition in Bash's manual, POSIX probably has something similar.)

So, anything that matches the regex `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*` (assuming ASCII character ranges) is a valid name for a variable. Unicode characters and punctuation don't work.

That's pretty much the set of characters supported in variable names in most programming languages, though some do support Unicode, too. Words beginning with digits are taken as numbers (note that stuff like `0xabcd` and `123e3` are often valid numbers), and the dash is usually taken as the minus operator, so `a-b` is a simple arithmetic operation of two variables, not one variable. And so on.

The parameters that aren't of that format are the numbered positional parameters (script/function arguments, assignable with `set`) and the [special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters). Note that `_` (a single underscore) is one of the latter, and while you can assign to it without an error, it's not much use since it resets immediately.

These are fine:

```
$ a123=foo __=bar
$ echo $a123 $__
foo bar
```

but:

```
$ _=foo echo bar >/dev/null 
$ echo $_
bar
```

As for the uppercase ones, there's a [list of the variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Variable-Index.html#Variable-Index) that are special to Bash or other Bourne-ish shells (ignore the readline variables, they're not related here). They all do seem to start with an uppercase letter, *except* that there's `histchars` that's all lowercase(!). Luckily, it only matters if history expansion is enabled.

Comment: You can have spaces either side of the egual sign in `var=value` in certain cases.  Example:  `(( var = 6 )); echo $var;`

Comment: You can have unicode characters as variable name, try to set your locale

Comment: @cuonglm, Doesn't work in Bash (Debian's `4.4.12(1)-release`). `LC_ALL=fi_FI.UTF-8  bash -c 'ä=123'` gives `bash: ä=123: command not found`. ksh and zsh seem to accept that, though.